# Alternate foreach output

Tags: c#, foreach

I have this code which grabs the specified text from a webpage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var pageContent = client.DownloadString("http://www.modern-railways.com");
        var regexTitle = new Regex(@"<span class='articleTitle'>(.+?)</span>");
        var regexDate = new Regex(@"class='summaryText' data-ajax='false'>(.+?)</a></p><div");


        foreach (Match title in regexTitle.Matches(pageContent))
        {
            var articleTitle = title.Groups[1].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(articleTitle);
        }

        foreach (Match date in regexDate.Matches(pageContent))
        {
            var articleDate = date.Groups[1].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(articleDate);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

As it is now it prints all the articleTitle first and then all the articleDate. How can I get out 1st line ArticleTitle, second line articleDate and so on?

Comment: Don't try to parse HTML with regular expressions. Use a tool specifically designed for parsing HTML, like the HTML Agility Pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ and `Zip` method:

```
var titles = regexTitles.Matches(pageContent).Cast<Match>();
var dates = regexDate.Matches(pageContent).Cast<Match>();

var source = titles.Zip(dates, (t, d) => new { Title = t, Date = d })

foreach (var item in source)
{
    var articleTitle = item.Title.Groups[1].Value;
    var articleDate = item.Date.Groups[1].Value;

    Console.WriteLine(articleTitle);
    Console.WriteLine(articleDate);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to resolve Zip because it is giving me errors.